# Integration between services in a SOA

Tags: design, architecture, web-services, domain-driven-design, soa

Assume we have a Bounded Context for Inventory (InventoryBC) and another one for Shipments (ShipmentsBC). These 2 BCs need to communicate together. They are hosted on 2 different services on different servers with different databases.

When a Shipment is made I might need to fetch some data from the Inventory BC so I think a REST GET request should solve it. However, when a shipment is done I need to decrease the Inventory so an Event "ShipmentCompleted" would do the trick.

However, what if one of the services is down? The writes aren't lost as they will be persisted in a Queue till their consumption, but what about the reads? No reads= nothing working

Does this style of integration work in practice or is there better approach for a more scalable and loosely coupled system?

Answer (score 1):

If I may rephrase your question, you are asking "what happens to my system if something breaks?"  Well, the short answer is that your system no longer functions properly. This happens all the time in complex systems. The degree to which you experience degraded functionality will depend upon what broke and how important it is. For example, when the space shuttle flew, there were certain points in the flight trajectory where we could lose an engine and still make it to orbit. Other places in the trajectory meant a return to launch site abort, while still others meant landing across the Atlantic (most likely Zaragoza, Spain).

In your specific case, the system does not appear to be that complex. Nonetheless, in any system, there will be parts that are more critical than others. Databases in computer systems are often designed at points where they can be a single point of failure. It can be extremely expensive and unnecessary to design these SPFs out of the system, so you have to live with the probability that the system will be down from time to time. Good design practices, including using federated databases and multiple geographic regions can reduce this risk.

I think you have the right approach - having several small, self-contained pieces with very limited interface boundaries is the best way to ensure reliability of the system overall.